# Moq fails because it expects a return value but doesn't let me provide it

Tags: c#, testing, moq

I have

```
Service.Setup(service => service.AsyncMethod(It.IsAny<Func<Task>>()));
```

where Service is a Mock and AsyncMethod accepts a `Func<Task>` and returns a `Task`. Normally in my code I simply `await service.AsyncMethod(..)`.

When I run this code as a Unit Test in Moq, it fails, giving me an exception `invocation failed with mock behavior Strict. Invocation needs to return a value and therefore must have a corresponding setup that provides it.`

Okay sure, I need to return a value. Then why can't I do

```
Service.Setup(service => service.AsyncMethod(It.IsAny<Func<Task>>())).Returns(..)
```

at all? It tells me that it cannot resolve the symbol 'Returns'. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Are you sure you have the parentheses correct?  Do you have an overload of `AsyncMethod` that returns `void`?

Comment: Functions can not be overloaded by simply changing the return type. Only the name and arguments determine which overload to use.

Comment: Yep, you're right @Steve.  Just trying to come up with something!

Comment: Ahh I feel dumb, I solved my own answer by specifying the return type of the setup method

Comment: Side note: try to always post exact error messages. "cannot resolve the symbol 'Returns'." does not sound like exact compile time message... It probably tells something like "can't figure out return type based on delegate you passed/null/..."

Comment: For future readers.  I got this same error message when I had a method (I didn't originate the method) that had an out parameter AND it had a return.  public bool MyMethod(out string myOutString);    I got the out parameter working, but forgot to do a return on the bool.  Anyway.  I simply did a ".Returns(true)" on my mock setup for MyMethod setup.  D'uh.  No idea why the original developers had an out parameter and a bool return on the method.

Answer (score 18):

It can be done such way:

```
Service.Setup(service => service.AsyncMethod(It.IsAny<Func<Task>>()))
    .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved my own question.

I have an interface Service

```
interface IService 
{
    Task asyncMethod(Func<Task> asyncFunc);
}
```

My Moq is like so

```
Mock<IService> Service = new Mock<IService>(MockBehavior.Strict);
Service.Setup(service => service.AsyncMethod(It.IsAny<Func<Task>>()));
```

I cannot specify a `.Returns()` value for the Setup because it doesn't understand the syntax, 'Returns' symbol not recognized. Changing it to this fixes it.

```
Service.Setup<Task>(service => service.AsyncMethod(It.IsAny<Func<Task>>()))
    .Returns<Func<Task>>(async (asyncFunc) => await asyncFunc.Invoke());
```

Comment: You likely don't need both `Setup<Task>` and `<Func<Task>>` - either should do ... Normally single cast of actual return value is enough like `.Returns((<Func<Task>>)(...))`